# how do I identify the @user.id using Restful Authentication?

Tags: restful-authentication

I just installed Restful Authentication.

After someone has successfully logged in, they write a review -- as you would a comment for a blog.

How do I know the value of the user_id column for the authenticater user so I can put that into the reviews table to match user to review?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of this, but try @current_user.id in your controller